# How do I trigger a button click during page_load?

Tags: asp.net

I have a few buttons created with a while loop and stored inside a placeholder, which when created have CommandArguments equal to unique fields from a single column of my database.
When clicked, the button's click procedure retrieves data from the database using the button's CommandArgument to determine what data to display.

My problem is when the page loads, I want the first of these buttons to be selected by default and its onClick event to be triggered. Is there a way to do this inside an `If Not Page.IsPostBack`, or do I have to resort to JavaScript/jQuery?

Here's my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<%@ Page Language="VB" Debug="true" ClientTarget="uplevel" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Data.OleDb" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Data" %>

<script runat="server">
    Dim dbConnection As OleDbConnection
    Dim dbCommand As OleDbCommand
    Dim dbReader As OleDbDataReader
    Dim sqlString As String

    Sub Page_Load()
        Try
            dbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" & Server.MapPath("MyDatabase.accdb"))
            dbConnection.Open()

            sqlString = "SELECT DISTINCT Type FROM MyTable"
            dbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlString, dbConnection)
            dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader()

            While dbReader.Read()
                Dim myButton As Button = New Button()
                myButton.ID = dbReader("Column2")
                myButton.Text = dbReader("Column2")
                myButton.CommandArgument = dbReader("Column2")
                myButton.EnableViewState = False
                AddHandler myButton.Command, AddressOf myClickSub
                myPlaceholder.Controls.Add(myButton)
            End While

            dbReader.Close()
        Finally
            dbConnection.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Sub myClickSub(src As Object, args As CommandEventArgs)
        Try
            dbConnection.Open()
            sqlString = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Column2 = '" & args.CommandArgument & "'"
            dbCommand.CommandText = sqlString
            dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader()

            myRepeater.DataSource = dbReader
            myRepeater.DataBind()

            dbReader.Close()
        Finally
            dbConnection.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
</script>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />   
        <title>My Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form runat="Server">
            <div>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="myPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                <br />
                <asp:Repeater id="myRepeater" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                                <th scope="col">Foo</th>
                                <th scope="col">Bar</th>
                            </tr>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td><%# Eval("Column1")%></td>
                                <td><%# Eval("Column3")%></td>
                                <td><%# Eval("Column4")%></td>
                            </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </table>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the first of these buttons to be selected by default

*Technically* you want the first record to *display* by default.  This is a separate concern from the clicking of a button.  So separate it into its own function:

```
Sub BindRepeater(ByVal column2 as String)
    Try
        dbConnection.Open()
        sqlString = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Column2 = '" & column2 & "'"
        dbCommand.CommandText = sqlString
        dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader()

        myRepeater.DataSource = dbReader
        myRepeater.DataBind()

        dbReader.Close()
    Finally
        dbConnection.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Then in the click handler:

```
Sub myClickSub(src As Object, args As CommandEventArgs)
    BindRepeater(args.CommandArgument)
End Sub
```

Now you can call that same function from `Page_Load`:

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack
    BindRepeater(someValue)
End If
```

(Where you get `someValue` is up to you.  I imagine it's something from the first record in the data source?)

---

Also, and ***this is important***, your data access code is wide open to SQL injection attacks.  You'll really *really* want to use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: When the button is clicked it changes colour, I just left the css part of my code out, sorry.

Comment: @JosephWebber: Are you not able to do that with this approach?  `Page_Load` can set the initial styling and the click handler can update the styling.

Comment: Would there not be an easier, shorter way to do this, like by calling myClickSub and giving it myPlaceholder.Controls.Item(0) as the first argument, and a CommandEventArgument as the second?

Comment: @JosephWebber: It doesn't get much shorter and easier than this.  All I've done is extract a function where more than one operation needed to use it.  It's so common a refactoring that Visual Studio has it built-in to a context menu.  You can certainly *try* to invoke the handler function directly and supply those parameters.  If that works for you, great.  But it's a tightly-coupled approach and while it may coincidentally work in this scenario it's not a good practice.  The point here is to separate the logic from the UI events.

Comment: I gotcha, best practice is best practice. Thanks for your insight, and I'll keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Hey add below code under the `Page.IsPostBack` event

```
btnSwitchToType1_Click(this, null);
```

Hope it helps